# External files wont load on site

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5, urlrequest

I am having trouble figuring out how fix a URLRequest loading problem. When I test my flash swf, the URLRequest works and loads a text file in a textfield that I have. The problem is when I upload the swf to a swfhost site or any site, the textfield doesn't show anything. I think the problem is that I have the external files locally and once the swf is uploaded, it checks the same folder, but can't find it. Below is a code that I have.

```
            if (introduction == true)
            {
                textLoader.load(new URLRequest("Texts/LV1introduction.txt"));
            }
            //GO UP A LEVEL
            else if (levelNum == 1)
            {
                textLoader.load(new URLRequest("Texts/LV1rise.txt"));
            }
            else if (levelNum == 2)
            {
                textLoader.load(new URLRequest("Texts/LV2rise.txt"));
            }
            else if (levelNum == 3)
            {
                textLoader.load(new URLRequest("Texts/LV3rise.txt"));
            }
```

How can I include my external text files when I upload my swf to a site?

Answer (score 0):

Try re-check your folder/file for Capital letters, that's one possibility when offline is a go-go and online is a no-no. When things go online, it's case sensitive.

so a folder "Texts/" and "texts/" will be different.

Let me know if that helps or not.